# How to make alert with python without pausing the running program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winapi

I have a program in python, and when I make an alert with win32api.py, the running program pauses, how do I make it continue working even if the alert is up?

This is the code example:

```
time.sleep(3)

win32api.MessageBox(0,'hello','text')

time.sleep(3)

os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM program.exe")
```

Now when it comes to the win32api.Mes... part it pauses the program until I click "OK", how to prevent it from pausing?

Thank you!

Comment: When you "make an alert with win32api", what exactly are you calling? If you call a function that creates a blocking modal alert, it will of course block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the MSDN docs explain, [`MessageBox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox):

> Displays a modal dialog box that contains a system icon, a set of buttons, and a brief application-specific message, such as status or error information. The message box returns an integer value that indicates which button the user clicked.

[A **modal** dialog box](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/modal-nonmodal-dialog/) is intended to block your program until it's dealt with. That's what it means: it puts your program into a special "waiting for the user" mode.

Plus, it obviously can't return what the user clicked unless it waits until the user clicks something.

If you really want to use `MessageBox`, you could push the rest of your work onto another thread, like this:

```
def background():
    time.sleep(3)
    os.system("TASKKILL /F /IM program.exe")
t = threading.Thread(target=background)
t.start()

time.sleep(3)
win32api.MessageBox(0,'hello','text')
```

Alternatively, you could [create a modeless dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlgbox/using-dialog-boxes#creating-a-modeless-dialog-box), but that requires integrating the rest of your program with a win32api event loop.

Comment: it was correct, but just a bonus question. if you are using windows 10, how to run notification on bottom right corner?

Comment: @crdw That's not an alert, or a dialog; that's a completely different API. See [Notirication Area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/notification-area) in MSDN for a language-agnostic tutorial. I don't know if there's anything more specific to pywin32 or not; if you've read the MSDN docs and need help converting it to pywin32 code, you should ask a separate question.

Comment: @crdw A search for examples of `Shell_NotifyIcon` in Python code turned up [this list](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/89844/win32gui.Shell_NotifyIcon). I can't vouch for how useful it is, but it's probably worth checking out before asking a question.

Comment: Ok, you helped out a lot!

Comment: @crdw: In case you are asking about the Windows 10 Toast Notification and Action Center, those are accessible by desktop applications as well. It's just very, *very* involved getting there. There's [sample code](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/DesktopToasts) (C++ and C#) should you dare investigating.

Comment: @IInspectable Can't you fire-and-forget a toast notification without anything too horrible involving Win8-style tiley-app-model stuff, and you only need that if you need to interact with them (but that includes even basic stuff like getting a callback when dismissed, not just active UIs)? But maybe I relied on some (third-party?) simple toast service or something to get that behavior; I don't remember very well.

Comment: You still have to activate the types, which is fairly tedious, first instantiating the type factories, and then activating the required types. And then you have to communicate with them through their COM interfaces. If there are pre-built libraries, this could be quite simple.